# PHP: Substituição de caracteres dentro de uma string a parti de uma determinada posição

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

Estou precisando de uma forma em PHP de substituir partes de strings a partir de uma posição dada, por exemplo:

String: **aaa**aaaaaaa
Substituir a partir do **3º** caracter por "-"
Resultado: aaa-------

ou

String: aaaaaaa**aaa**
Substituir até o **7º** caracter por "-"
Resultado: -------aaa

ou

String: aaaaaaaaaa
Substituir ou a parti de qualquer posição até qual quer outra
Resultado: aa------aa
Resultodo: ---aaa----

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**ideone**](https://ideone.com/3ZDJOT)

```
$str = "aaaaaaaaaa";
$carater="-";
$apartir=3;
$ate=7;
$ambos="ambos";
$entre="entre";
$compr=strlen($str);

if ($apartir==3){
 $nome=substr($str, $compr-$apartir, $compr);
 $right = str_pad($nome, $compr, $carater, STR_PAD_RIGHT);
}

if ($ate==7){
  $nome=substr($str, $compr-$apartir, $compr);
  $left = str_pad($nome, $compr, $carater, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

if($ambos=="ambos"){
    $nome=substr($str, $ate, $compr);
    $both = str_pad($nome, $compr, $carater, STR_PAD_BOTH);
}

    echo $right;
    echo "\n";
    echo $left;
    echo "\n";
    echo $both;
    echo "\n";

$quant=2;

$parts = str_split($str, $quant);
$inicio = $fim = $parts[0]; 

$aux=substr($str,$quant*2,$compr);

$compl=str_replace("a",$carater,$aux);

$meio=$inicio.$compl.$fim;
echo $meio;
```

Referencias:

[strlen](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strlen.php)

[substr](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php)

[str_pad](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-pad.php)

[str_split](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-split.php)

Comment: Leo muito grato, era exatamente o que eu precisava. Foi de grande auxílio.